# Counting the amount of Days in a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to get a query that will multiply a static number by the amount of days in a date range the problem i'm having is that when a single day is selected it returns a result of 0 instead of 1: Ex:

```
Declare @Startdate DATE
Declare @enddate DATE
SET @Startdate='9/1/2013'
SET @enddate='9/1/2013' 
SELECT 1154*(Select DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdate, @enddate))
```

This example returns 0 instead of 1. Should I be using something other than DateDiff?

Additional clarification - This will be used as part of a report where the date range will be dynamically entered by person calling the report.

Comment: Why should it return `1`?, the difference in days for those 2 dates is `0`. If you want to count the number of days, then just add `1` to that. `SELECT 1154*(DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdate, @enddate)+1)`

Comment: What should it return if `@startdate='9/1/2013'` and `@enddate='9/2/2013'`?  Should this also be 1?  Or are all of your ranges off by 1?

Comment: I want it to include that as a day even though its not actually "between" the range. adding the +1 accounts for the first day in the range. For example i wanted 9/1/2013 - 9/10/2013 to be 10 as it would include 9/1 in the range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could just add 1:

```
Declare @Startdate DATE
Declare @enddate DATE
SET @Startdate='9/1/2013'
SET @enddate='9/1/2013' 
SELECT (DATEDIFF(day,@Startdate,@enddate)+1)*1154
```

Update, as noted don't need the inner `SELECT`

Comment: Is it "SELECT (1154*(Select DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdate, @enddate)))+1" ??

Comment: @ConsultYarla Why?, the way that it's done now is what op wants: *multiply a static number by the amount of days in a date range*

Comment: And that just goes to prove, that sometimes its the simple things. That accomplishes exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!